# How to animate grid in canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have canvas. In canvas i have 3 grids. And I can't animate them. I want to make slideshow with grids.

Here my xamll code:

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas1" Width="200" Height="300" Background="AliceBlue">
        <Grid Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Right="200" Background="Red" Name="grid1">
        </Grid>
        <Grid Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Right="400" Background="Blue" Name="grid2">
        </Grid>
        <Grid Canvas.Left="400" Canvas.Right="600" Background="Black" Name="grid3">
        </Grid>
        <Button Panel.ZIndex="1" Width="50" Height="50" Content="NEXT" Click="Button_Click">
        </Button>
    </Canvas>
```

Here my c# code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
            TranslateTransform trans2 = new TranslateTransform();
            grid1.RenderTransform = trans;
            grid2.RenderTransform = trans2;
            Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
            DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
            DoubleAnimation da1 = new DoubleAnimation();

            da = new DoubleAnimation(200, 0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            da1 = new DoubleAnimation(0, -200, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));


            Storyboard.SetTarget(da1, grid1);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da1, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"));

            Storyboard.SetTarget(da, grid2);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"));

            storyboard.Children.Add(da1);
            storyboard.Children.Add(da);

            //this.BeginStoryboard(storyboard, HandoffBehavior.SnapshotAndReplace, true);
            FrameworkElement sd = new FrameworkElement();
            sd.BeginStoryboard(storyboard, HandoffBehavior.Compose, true);
        }
```

For now, i want to animate only 2 grids. i press button, and nothing happened.
I need to animate from the code.

Comment: Conducting this animation isn't a good idea from my experience. I would take a look into placing the animate in the window.resources then applying it to the element from the code behind if you can't directly apply it to the element from your xaml. Aside from that the storyboard probably isn't being raised to the UI, try encapsulating that code in `this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {"do work"}));` This way the action is invoked by the window dispatcher thread and will be raised to the UI.

Comment: @CalebB I create function "make()" and copy-paste all code there. In button click event i write "this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => make())); "; But also, nothing happened

Comment: In that case your launching another action from the action being invoked, you need to encapsulate the changes being made not another method.

Comment: @CalebB, Could you provide some example, or link to read about it?

Comment: Also in your code your running the animation on your element sd and not the element but said element is never added anywhere for it to be visible. Example for Dispatcher.Invoke(): `this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { for (int x = 100; x < 500; x += 20) { this.Height = x; Thread.Sleep(500); } } ));`

Comment: @CalebB, firstly my problem is: grids not visible in canvas.

Comment: Your not creating a grid but a FrameworkElement and said element is never added to your canvas. In your code here you can empty grids in a canvas that are never touched by your animation in the code behind. I would do a little more research on the subject and come back to this. Without an understanding of those concepts these desired actions will be very difficult to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

That's how I do it:

Fist the button outside of the Canvas and place the Canvas in a Grid that has a Clip with the size of the objects inside the Canvas, I set 200x200 as example:

```
<Grid Width="200" Height="200">
    <Grid.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry  Rect="0,0,200,200"/>
    </Grid.Clip>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas1"  Background="AliceBlue" >
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <Grid Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Right="200" Width="200" Height="200" Background="Red" Name="grid1">
        </Grid>
        <Grid Canvas.Left="200" Canvas.Right="400" Width="200" Height="200" Background="Blue" Name="grid2">
        </Grid>
        <Grid Canvas.Left="400" Canvas.Right="600" Width="200" Height="200" Background="Black" Name="grid3">
        </Grid>
        <Grid Canvas.Left="400" Canvas.Right="600" Width="200" Height="200" Background="Orange" Name="grid4">
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
    <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Height="50" Content="NEXT" Click="Button_Click">
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

And now the logic for the button event

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var offsetX = (canvas1.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform).X;
        var finalX = offsetX - 200;
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();

        var da = new DoubleAnimation(offsetX, finalX, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        Storyboard.SetTarget(da, canvas1);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"));

        sb.Children.Add(da);
        sb.Begin();
    }
```

I think is easy to understand and just one storyboard.
I hope it is the solution for your case.